# Is there a tool that will track/log managed code?

Tags: debugging, logging

I'm working on a bug where we have a use case that works, and a subtly different use case that doesn't. The code base has next to no logging, and I don't want to spend time now sprinkling logging throught the code base, though I do have time budgeted to do that at a later date.

Is there a tool that logs a program's actions ie, logs each function call?

Apparently Appsight does do this but costs 100,000's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using our logging tool [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/) together with the aspect oriented programming (AOP) framework [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). By using our [aspect library](http://code.gurock.com/p/smartinspect-postsharp/), you can automatically instrument and log all method calls, exceptions and even field/property changes.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't require any code change / recompile would be to use a tool that's based on the .NET Profiling API, which injects its hooks at runtime.

The only free-open-source project i know that traces not just method entry/exit but also the return values/method parameters is [SAE (Simple Assembly Explorer)](http://code.google.com/p/simple-assembly-explorer/).  When you open it up, just navigate to your exe, right click on it, and choose Profile.

There are some limits to this tool - specifically, it won't print out the values of generic types, and the text output is not indented/prettified.

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) can log each function call with parameters for .NET 2.0 - 4.0 applications without any additional instrumentation.